# Add event user availability section Event in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, event

I developed a visualforce page Event StandardController but I want to add the assigned user event calendar component, I mean this section:

[image]

There is a way to set this section in visualforce?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well after been searching I decided to use FullCalendar http://fullcalendar.io/ and show the user event as related list in my visualforce, by now is a quickly solution.

It looks like this:

[image]